# Navicat premium on ubuntu ./start_navicat

Tags: ubuntu, navicat

I'm trying to run `Navicat` on My `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`

when I write this command `./start_navicat`

The result is :

```
./start_navicat: 79: [: /home/mohammad/Documents/navicat111_premium_en: unexpected operator
./start_navicat: 79: [: /home/mohammad/Documents/navicat111_premium_en: unexpected operator
./start_navicat: 79: [: /home/mohammad/Documents/navicat111_premium_en: unexpected operator
```

And i didn't find any answer for this problem.

Line 79

```
if [ ! -h "$WINEPREFIX/drive_c/windows/system32/$dll_name" ] || [ `readlink "$WINEPREFIX/drive_c/windows/system32/$dll_name"` != "$navicat_root/$WINEDIR/drive_c/windows/system32/$dll_name" ] ; then
```

Line 80

```
rm -rf "$WINEPREFIX/drive_c/windows/system32/$dll_name"
```

Line 81

```
ln -s "$navicat_root/$WINEDIR/drive_c/windows/system32/$dll_name" "$WINEPREFIX/drive_c/windows/system32/$dll_name"
```

Line 82

```
fi
```

Comment: looks like there's an issue in the script on line 79.  What is on line 79 of the script?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem six weeks ago.
I downloaded the latest version again, installed it to /usr/share/
and I **have to** start it with `sudo ./start_navicat`
Hope that helps!

P.S.: Wine is installed? (check in terminal: `which wine`)